Can I cash/deposit a cheque without a UK bank account or address?
So I moved abroad and cancelled my UK bank account, assuming they would ask me where to wire the money left in it. Instead they sent a cheque to my old UK address. I can get someone to pick that up for me but since it's in my name they cannot cash it. I also do not have a UK address anymore, nor do I have a UK bank account. Additionally, no bank in my current country of residence accepts cheques anymore.
Is there a way for me to get this cheque cashed?

Have you asked the bank? If so, what did they say. If not, do so.

@TripeHound The bank cannot wire me the money since they already sent the cheque and I can't deposit it with them since I don't have an account anymore and I don't live in the UK so I can't open a new account legally. Something like Revolut will allow me to open a UK account but they don't accept cheques.

How much is it roughly? Tens, hundreds, thousands? That might affect the feasibility of any options.

@Fluxquark are you saying "The bank cannot wire me the money since they already sent the cheque" based on your own assumption, or based on talking to them? They should be able to cancel any cheque they've issued (especially if you can arrange for it to be returned to them) and then wire you the money by some alternative means.

@Vicky The issue might be more that the bank doesn't want to wire the money and has no reason to do so. They can't keep the money but they satisfied that part by sending out the check. OP is not a customer there anymore and living in a different country, nothing to gain from being nice or accomodating to them. So they consider the transaction finished and see no reason to do anything else for OP.

Generally, your local bank should be able to cash that check. That's what banks do. Even if they don't accept checks as a rule, they should be able to handle this transaction. Expect high fees, long time for processing, and unfavorable currency conversion rates. You might be required to open a GBP account to deposit it. If your current country of residency has stringent controls on foreign currency then you may be out of luck.
Alternatively you may be able to cash that check in the UK, by walking into the bank that issued the check (maybe even that specific branch) and presenting your id. Call and ask. But if you're far away the trip may not be worth it.
If the check is not endorsable (crossed, as most UK checks are nowadays), there's not a lot of other options. You should have asked before closing the account what they're going to do.
It's hard to give more detailed answers without knowing what country you're at now.
